# How can i use java class under swing JButton?

Tags: java, swing, bluetooth, bluecove

how can i use java class under a swing jButton?this is the code i want to link with the button. this code will discover the bluetooth devices and will send a text file to the connected device.I have used bluecove library.

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.bluetooth.DataElement;
import javax.bluetooth.DeviceClass;
import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryAgent;
import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryListener;
import javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.RemoteDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.ServiceRecord;
import javax.bluetooth.UUID;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.obex.ClientSession;
import javax.obex.HeaderSet;
import javax.obex.Operation;
import javax.obex.ResponseCodes;


public class MyDiscoveryListener implements DiscoveryListener{

private static Object lock=new Object();
public ArrayList<RemoteDevice> devices;

public MyDiscoveryListener() {
    devices = new ArrayList<RemoteDevice>();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyDiscoveryListener listener =  new MyDiscoveryListener();

    try{
        LocalDevice localDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        DiscoveryAgent agent = localDevice.getDiscoveryAgent();
        agent.startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC, listener);

        try {
            synchronized(lock){
                lock.wait();
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }


        System.out.println("Device Inquiry Completed. ");


        UUID[] uuidSet = new UUID[1];
        uuidSet[0]=new UUID(0x1105); //OBEX Object Push service

        int[] attrIDs =  new int[] {
                0x0100 // Service name
        };

        for (RemoteDevice device : listener.devices) {
            agent.searchServices(
                    attrIDs,uuidSet,device,listener);


            try {
                synchronized(lock){
                    lock.wait();
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }


            System.out.println("Service search finished.");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



@Override
public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice btDevice, DeviceClass arg1) {
    String name;
    try {
        name = btDevice.getFriendlyName(false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        name = btDevice.getBluetoothAddress();
    }

    devices.add(btDevice);
    System.out.println("device found: " + name);

}

@Override
public void inquiryCompleted(int arg0) {
    synchronized(lock){
        lock.notify();
    }
}

@Override
public void serviceSearchCompleted(int arg0, int arg1) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        lock.notify();
    }
}

@Override
public void servicesDiscovered(int transID, ServiceRecord[] servRecord) {
    for (int i = 0; i < servRecord.length; i++) {
        String url = servRecord[i].getConnectionURL(ServiceRecord.AUTHENTICATE_NOENCRYPT, true);
        if (url == null) {
            continue;
        }
        DataElement serviceName = servRecord[i].getAttributeValue(0x0100);
        if (serviceName != null) {
            System.out.println("service " + serviceName.getValue() + " found " + url);
            sendMessageToDevice(url);
            if(serviceName.getValue().equals("OBEX Object Push")){
                sendMessageToDevice(url);                
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("service found " + url);
        }


    }
}

private static void sendMessageToDevice(String serverURL){
    try{
        System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverURL);

        ClientSession clientSession = (ClientSession) Connector.open(serverURL);
        System.out.println(clientSession.toString());
        HeaderSet hsConnectReply = clientSession.connect(null);
        System.out.println("Reply: " + hsConnectReply.toString());
        if (hsConnectReply.getResponseCode() != ResponseCodes.OBEX_HTTP_OK) {
            System.out.println("Failed to connect");
            return;
        }

        HeaderSet hsOperation = clientSession.createHeaderSet();
        hsOperation.setHeader(HeaderSet.NAME, "do u want to encrypt/decrypt");
        hsOperation.setHeader(HeaderSet.TYPE, "text");

        System.out.println("Operation: " + hsOperation.toString());
        //Create PUT Operation
        Operation putOperation = clientSession.put(hsOperation);
        System.out.println("Putt  Operation: " + putOperation.toString());
        // Send some text to server
        byte data[] = "Hello World !!!".getBytes("iso-8859-1");
        hsOperation.setHeader(hsOperation.LENGTH, new Long(data.length));
        OutputStream os = putOperation.openOutputStream();
        System.out.println("Writing the data: " + data[0]);
        os.write(data);
        os.close();

        putOperation.close();

        clientSession.disconnect(null);

        clientSession.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Your question is asked in a way that suggests that you've not done any searching on this subject for tutorials or similar questions, and that's not the best way to ask questions on this (or on any site). Please check for the appropriate tutorials first. For example, this simple [jbutton tutorial search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jbutton%20tutorial) will lead you right to the main tutorial on the first hit.

Comment: So what is the problem? Please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a Java application with a button that executes functionality from your `MyDiscoveryListener` class (like for example calling a `searchForServices` method), you could do something like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class BluetoothButton {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new BluetoothButton().createAndShowGui());
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stack Overflow");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton button = new JButton("Search for services");

        button.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
            MyDiscoveryListener listener =  new MyDiscoveryListener();
            listener.searchForServices();
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(button);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't *link* in Java. Instead, you create an object that implements the *ActionListener* interface.

Like in this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) directly at Oracle.

In general: if your knowledge about Java is really that small - please consider learning about such bascis before doing anything else for now. Especially "UI" related Java coding isn't easy to learn by trial and error. You should step back and spent some serious time in learning/understanding the concepts around that!